# wifi stops working on linux 6.6 on fedora kinoite and says "no connections" when i to use the kde applet to connect to wifi i get nothing at all

Tags: filesystems, hardware

I've tried turning it off and on again,rolling back and reupdating it,i even reseat my net card but nothing changed.
the network adapter i'm using is the ralink corp, RT 2790 wireless 802.11n 1T/2R PCIe